# Can sawtooth be used as a permissionless blockchain?

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, ethereum, hyperledger-sawtooth, iota

I know large number of public blockchains are around but i realy love the flexibility that hyperledger sawtooth provides so is it a good idea to use sawtooth as a public permissionless blockchain?
I can't use Ethereum because it is not feasible for microtransactions and is not scalable.
I can't use IOTA as it does not have smart contracts enabled with it.

Comment: Transaction submissions require a public/private credential however; it is feasible to setup a REST process that accepts transactions from anywhere and proxies the transaction in. You can also consider using sawtooth as the system of record and instrument the TP to emit Events, which you could intercept and write to an off-chain DB with more querying flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can allow any client to create a transaction and add it to the blockchain.

That said, it's probably not wise to put a premissionless blockchain on the open, public Internet as it may be subject to abuse. Or at least you need to consider measures to mitigate abuse, as a blockchain is immutable--transactions can only be "reversed" with another transaction. For example, put the client interface behind a login or other authentication.